# Is it possible to change the value returned by Server.GetLastError()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah, httpmodule

I have written an HttpModule for ASP.NET which will inspect the current exception (if any) and wrap it in a new exception with a unique identifier.  Then I want Elmah to log that wrapping exception.

My module is working and is sitting in front of the Elmah module, however I can't work out how to change the Server.GetLastError() so that my new exception will be logged!

I have tried:

```
var originalException = context.Server.GetLastError();
var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
var context = app.Context;
context.ClearError();
context.AddError(new WrapperException(originalException));
```

But doing so makes the context.Error property return null.
In fact ClearError doesn't do what it's advertised to do: ["Clears all errors for the current HTTP request."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.clearerror?view=netframework-4.7.2)
It doesn't do this.  The AllErrors array still contains exceptions; all it does make GetLastError return null.

You cannot set context.AllErrors, nor poke something into the array (it's a copy).

You also cannot throw a new exception: the error page only sees the original exception, and Elmah doesn't even log it.

I'm beginning to think that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you want to replace `Server.GetLastError()` is to make sure that ELMAH logs the right exceptions, there may be a better approach. ELMAH's filtering feature can be used to override the logged exception. To do so, add the following code to your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```cs
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
    ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(new Error(new WrapperException(args.Exception)));
    args.Dismiss();
}
```

The `ErrorLog_Filtering` method is called by ELMAH just before logging any uncaught exceptions to the configured error log. In the example, I pull the information about the error happening (`args.Context` and `args.Exception`) and wrap the thrown exception in a new exception (`WrapperException`). By logging the new exception using the `ErrorLog.GetDefault(...).Log(...)` method, I make sure that ELMAH doesn't call the `ErrorLog_Filtering` method recursively (it would if you used `ErrorSignal...Raise()`). Finally, I dismiss the original exception, to avoid the error being logged twice.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will play with it and see where it leads, however I still want my error page to receive the wrapper exception in my error page to display the ID to the user.

Comment: I see. Then you probably want to go with the module and handler idea.